# Reuse a class's method in the main.py

Tags: python

I've searched a lot about how to reuse a method from a class in the main.py file. i got some similar and basic solutions but in my case is a bit different.

**/lib/module.py**

```
class Myclass:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.thisX = x

    def check(self):
        if self.thisX == 2:
            print("this is fine. going to print it")
            self.printing()

    # this method will use in this class and must use from the main.py
    # the parameter "z" is gonna use only when the method will call from main.py
    def printing(self, z):
        if z == 1 :
            print("we got ", z)
        else:
            print(self.x)
```

**/main.py**

```
from lib.module import Myclass

# this is how i use the check() method once in my main.py
Myclass(2).check()

# the Myclass() gets "2" only once at the beginning of the program...
# i don't wanna pass "2" to the Myclass() everytime that i wanna use the printing() method...
c = Myclass()
c.printing(1)
```

**error**

```
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'x'
```

**testing**:

if i don't use the def **init**(), everything will be fine. but the problem is i need to keep it

Comment: you have declared your initializer to take an argument 'x' but you don't pass any argument to it. in main.py you can change c = Myclass() to c = Myclass(2)

Comment: You should put that as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line in **main.py**:

```
c = Myclass()
```

Calls this function:

```
class Myclass:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.thisX = x
```

Every time you create an instance of Myclass it will call the `__init__()` function. You declared it to take 2 arguments: `self` and `x`. `self` is always passed implicitly because it's a class, but you need to give it an argument 'x'.

So you can change **main.py** to this for example:

```
c = Myclass(2) # here x = 2
c.printing(1)
```

Please read [this for more information](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html)

Also, in general, class names are written in CapWords style so [it's a good idea](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#class-names) to call your class `MyClass` instead of `Myclass`

**Edit:**

Since you don't want to pass `x` to `__init__()` and you want to set `x` from **main.py** you can try something like this:

```
class Myclass:
  x = 0
  def check(self):
    if self.x == 2:
      print("x is 2")
```

from **main.py** you can do:

```
Myclass.x = 2; #this only needs to be done once
Myclass().check()
```

Output:

```
x is 2
```

Comment: i've edited the question with some comments. pls take a look. 
I found the similar answer but my im trying to ask how can i reuse my method without adding "2" everytime to the Myclass().

Comment: @ardi then instead of passing '2' to __init__() you can assign it inside of the function: self.thisX = 2

Comment: the value of "2" comes from the main.py. im not able to assign it manually into the __init__(). 
i was thinking about other ways to share the x variable in the Myclass() . 
if i can share the x value in another way in Myclass(), i can just delete the __init__() so i won't have the problem... ! (just my thoughts)

Answer (score 0):

I think @richflow 's answer hit the point. If some variable is to be shared by all instances of a class, it's logical to assign its value using `Myclass.x = new_number`. Then all instances of this class will know the change. 
If you really want to optionally change x in the `__init__`  method of an instance, you can still do it. Combining with @richflow's codes, it can look like the following.

```
class Myclass:
      x = 0
      def __init__(self, x=None):
        if x is not None:
          Myclass.x = x
          # other codes for initializiing the instance

      def check(self):
        if Myclass.x == 2:
          print("this is fine. going to print it")

      def printing(self, z=0):
            if z == 1 :
                print("we got ", z)
            else:
                print(Myclass.x)
```

I tried not to change too much from your codes. Your `main.py` should work correctly with this class definition. However, the design looks a bit weird to me. Probably that's because I didn't understand clearly what the `check` and `printing` methods are really doing, and what the argument `z` is really doing in `printing` methods. If you provides more insights, probably people can help you with a better design.